# Authentication in openUI5 how i can do this?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

hello guys I would like to ask for help from you, I am developing my first application using openUI5, this application is already well advanced thanks to the help of the forums here and some research I did. however, I came across a problem in which I don't know how to proceed. in my application it will be necessary to register and login, so i did a search and found q many do this part of login using JWT, then i did the same i did a backend application to make this token available to me, however i don't know how to effectively use it in my project .

I currently have an API running, in ASP.NET, on a machine at AMAZON that when running it I get the token but I don't know what to do exactly with that token if someone can pass me the way of what I will be very grateful.

anyone who can provide me with an example or something in that sense would be very useful

Comment: Well I would guess that you have to pass the token to your requests, this ofc depends on your API. Maybe you have to pass the token as a header-parameter or something like that.

Comment: but the problem is how i never worked before if these kind of applications with login, i don't know what i'm supposed to do.
I don't know if i need keep this token ( i think yes ) , i don't know where ai need to keep this and where i should put some verify to check if it is logged